# vue.js reactivity and data with mixin

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to set a flag that can be a boolean value `true` or `false` based on certain conditions.

```
// main.js
new Vue({
    el: `#app`,
    render: h => h(App,{
      props:{
        todoID: this.dataset.id
      }
    })
  })
```

my App script

```js
export default {
  name: 'App',
  props: {
    todoID: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isDone: false // here is the initial flag
    }
  },
  ...
```

I created a mixin method

```
import Vue from "vue";

Vue.mixin({
    methods: {
        isCompleted() {
            if (myconditions){
                this.isDone = true; // I want to change the flag to true
            }
        },
    },
});
```

in my template if I do `{{isDone}}` I always get false, how can I change this to be reactive so it can be changed based on the conditions?

Here is a demo I created: https://codesandbox.io/embed/vigorous-bell-p1itu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Can you add complete code? I want to see your mixin function call.

Comment: It is called inside a template {{isCompleted(some variables)}}. If i do console log i can see that functions runs but not able to change the value of isDone

Comment: So it means your boolean value is not passing to isCompleted function.

Comment: okay, let's work on it. Can you see the below answer. Let's try this and see.

Answer (score 0):

```js
Vue.mixin({
    methods: {
        isCompleted(myconditions) {
            console.log(myconditions);
            console.log(typeof myconditions);
              return  this.isDone = myconditions; // I want to change the flag to true
            
        },
    },
});
new Vue({
    el: '#vue-app',
    data: {
        isDone: false 
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

        <div id="vue-app">
            <p> result = {{ isCompleted(true) }}</p>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: This did not resolve the issue

Comment: Hey @Rain, can you check. Is that okay?

Comment: This is more like [what I want to do](https://codesandbox.io/embed/zen-parm-fmxo5?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Cool, peace out bro. Don't forget to vote up :) thanks

Comment: sorry your response did not resolve my issue, the link what I sent is what I want to do

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because I didn't see in your code where this `isDone` variable is being changed.
I made a demonstration with a function changing this variable through the same method done in your mixin.

[example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/zen-parm-fmxo5?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)